# My directory now has a branch (master) How do I fix this?

Tags: git, repository

One of my directories has a master branch and I would like to fix that. It was a directory but now it seems to be a git repository now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything git related is in the .git directory. If you accidentally initialized a directory just delete the .git dir from that directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this but how to delete it?

Comment: Are you asking how to delete a directory? Just like you would any other directory. If you are on the terminal navigate to the directory and ```rm -rf .git/``` but be sure you want to remove this dir from version control